# Accepting parameters on urls.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to access a function with two IDs and sending a message via POST to make a small chat function. The problem is that when I do this, I get a 403 (forbidden).

How I save this on the database is very simple: There is a table with 2 keys corresponding to each person, and I concatenate on a conversation field.

I make the call via JQuery:

```
        $('#send-message').bind("enterKey",function(e){
            alert("CLINK");
            $.post( "url/to/send/message/{{personA.id}}/{{personB_id}}", function( data ) {
                $( "#container" ).html( data );
            });
        });
        $('#send-message').keyup(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode == 13)
            {
            $(this).trigger("enterKey");
            }
        });
```

And process it:

```
def conversation_add(request, trainer_id, trainee_id):
    new_convo = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = HttpRequest.getlist("messgae")
        convo = Conversation.objects.filter(trainer=trainer_id, trainee=trainee_id)
        new_convo = convo.conversation + text + "\n"
    return render_to_response("plain.html", {'res':new_convo}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am not too sure if this is all relevant as to why I get the 403, but I decided to post it and explain anyway just in case.

Is there anything I need to take in consideration regarding Django's internals to be able to make this call?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the CSRF token in your ajax post?

Comment: What is `data` ? Does data have the `csrf_token` in it ?  Also `text = HttpRequest.getlist("messgae")` should be `text = request.getlist("messgae")`.

Comment: @danielcorreia clearly not, as he doesn't seem to be sending *any* data at all with the POST (the Ajax call just has a URL and a callback).

Comment: Right, I stumbled upon the 403 before I actually checked if I was sending the data. I will modify the post to properly show the example when I can.

Comment: @karthikr text = request.getlist gave me an error. 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting the [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) which would explain the 403 forbidden response.

You will need to add the `{% csrf_token %}` as normal in your template then add a pre-request callback function beforeSend on your AJAX POST to send the token:

```
beforeSend: function (request) {
   request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken",
       $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val());
   },
```

You can also disable the protection but I would advise against this.